# Hexadecimal being truncated

Tags: c, hex, printf

Why is it that when I attempt to print the value of `argv` (which according to Eclipse for a particular run of the program below was `0x7fffffffd958`) do I get `ffffd958` instead of `7fffffffd958`?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%x \n", argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you lie to your compiler like this? `argv` is a `char **`, not an `unsigned int`, so cast to `void *` and use `"%p"` instead of `"%x"`.

Comment: I know _print the value of `argv`_ is what you said, and all the comments and answers are addressing, but is it possible that you really intended to ask _print the value contained in `argv`_?

Comment: @ryyker perhaps, it's not often you are interested in *where* the `char*` array provided resides in memory.

Comment: @ ryyker I was looking to print the actual value of argv, not what it contains. Thanks for checking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: you are invoking *undefined behavior* because of wrong format specifier. Use instead:

```
printf("%p \n", (void *) argv);
```

The reason why you get different value is that `%x` treats `argv` as 32-bit unsigned integer on your platform. You could *probably* use `%lx` (or possibly `%llx`), but it is still bad and incorrect practice, since `argv` is of pointer type.

Comment: My understanding is that a pointer stores a memory address. By printing the pointer argv in the way I do above, is it correct to say that I'm printing the address in memory of the start of the array argv is pointing to? What is that address stored as (ie what is the type)?

Comment: It's an address, where the start of the pointer array resides, the *value* of `argv`, which is the base address of an array of `char*` pointers.

Comment: The address is a hexadecimal value? 0x7fffffffd958 in this case?

Comment: That's the output format of `%p`. Decimal expressed pointer values are not very meaningful in computer architecture.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%p\n", (void*)argv);
    return 0;
}
```

This will take care of the size of the pointer type, as opposed to the size of `unsigned int`, which might not be the same. The format `%p` requires a `void*` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using `%p` to print a `void *` is correct, but the output from `%p` is implementation-defined (so it is documented) and it does vary between platforms.  In particular, some platforms output a leading `0x`, some do not.  I think they all use hex, but even that's not mandated ([`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)):

> `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

An alternative uses C99 facilities from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
printf("0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)argv);
```

Technically, `uintptr_t` is an optional type.  In practice, I don't know of a system where it isn't available (but some mainframes or similar computers would be likely candidates if there is an exception).  This allows you to control the format — I like upper-case hex except for the leading dip `0xFEDCBA987654321` as it is uniform height, whereas `0xfedcba9876543210` has dips for `a`, `c`, and `e`.  YMMV!